# Javascript callback execute after user input on modal

Tags: javascript

I am writing a game, and I have a javascript function that calls a modal to get a dice roll so I need to stop execution of that function until the result of the dice roll. I looked into callbacks and promises but was unable to sort it out to get the functionality I need. Here is my code.

```
function docombat()
{
    getplayerroll("1d20","initiative")
}
function getplayerroll(dice,reason)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl",
        type:"post",
        data:{dice:dice,reason:reason},
        success: function(newHTML, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            $(newHTML).appendTo('body').modal({
                escapeClose: false,
                clickClose: false,
                showClose: false
            });
        }
    });

    //something like wait for the dice to be rolled and keep going
}
```

And then the modal

```
    <div id="diceroll""></div>
```

modal js

```
 function after_roll(res) { diceroll.innerHTML = res; }
```

so i need something in the original function that waits for after_roll()

Comment: From what I can see, it looks you're posting to a server to get the player's dice roll, which you are appending the response html to the body. Could you explain how, where and when the `after_roll(res)` function would be called and where the `res` value is obtained?

Comment: yes it is an ajaxed in modal it then goes through a series of functions to get the result of the dice then calls after_roll() but its all appended to the same body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using [jQuery Modal](http://jquerymodal.com/) from the style of construction. In which case you should be able to use custom events to achieve your desired control-flow:

```
function getplayerroll(dice,reason)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl",
        type:"post",
        data:{dice:dice,reason:reason},
        success: function(newHTML, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            $(newHTML).appendTo('body').modal({
                escapeClose: false,
                clickClose: false,
                showClose: false
            })

            // register the event handler
            .on('dice-rolled', onDiceRolled);
        }
    });

    //something like wait for the dice to be rolled and keep going
    function onDiceRolled(evt)
    {
      // carry on with the execution here....
    }
}
```

modal js

```
function after_roll(res)
{
    diceroll.innerHTML = res;

    // Trigger the event to activate the continuation
    $.modal.getCurrent().$elm.trigger('dice-rolled', { /* stick data here */ });
}
```

Comment: i actually ended up using    $("body").one("dice-rolled", function(){
      console.log("dice rolled"); 
    }); i think it will work just fine but you were very helpful with the trigger

Comment: @John No worries. Glad it helped you.